# Need a average value in interval of every time

Tags: python, sql

I have a table of the type below, and I need to bring the average of the values ​​in an interval of every 40 minutes, but I'm not getting it

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 01/08/2022 00:01 | 0,223195001 |
| 01/08/2022 00:21 | 0,221565172 |
| 01/08/2022 00:42 | 0,219373211 |
| 01/08/2022 01:12 | 0,220456049 |
| 01/08/2022 01:32 | 0,221331328 |
| 01/08/2022 01:52 | 0,205459893 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: do you want to solve this in sql or python?

Comment: I no have preference, either will do